# How to create editable tables in Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, tables, microsoft-excel

Is there any way to create editable tables using Adobe illustrator ? I would like to populate the table rows and columns with data from an excel sheet.

Things I have done so far :

- Created a text document from the excel sheet and imported it in illustrator.
- Formated the text in to rows and columns using spaces.
- Created a custom table illustration using rectangle tool in the background.

Limitations :

- Couldn't achieve required table cell spacing as the tab spacing increment by 8 spaces.
- Couldn't edit individual columns.
- Too much effort is need for large table datas with too many columns and rows.

Answer (score 3):

Illustrator is just not built for the volume of tables and formatting you need. Better look at InDesign for this: https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/creating-tables.html

Answer (score 0):

Since you have excel, I assume you have PowerPoint.

You can create a table in PowerPoint, add your information into that, then you can copy/paste the entire table into Illustrator, and it will translate it into paths.

Even the text will be editable in Illustrator so this is a good way to get a general table size and number of rows/columns. Then you can continue to edit the table however you want using Illustrator tools.

Answer (score 0):

I [built one](https://github.com/Lenniott/IllustratorTableMaker) i dunno how useful it would be for others

here is a link to a video I made showing how it works
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2HDY3C3Sww8